# Find and replace in MathType equations

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

Is it possible to change `Det` to `det` in all MathType equations?

Comment: There are probably many people here who know Microsoft Word inside out, forwards and backwards, but who don't know MathType.  Please put a bit more background information into your question; e.g., steps for creating an equation that we could use for testing.  (If you don’t understand what I’m asking for, use a comment to ask for clarification.  If you *do* understand what I’m asking for, don't respond in a comment; [edit] the question to make it more informative.)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the version of Word you're using and on which OS, but the following macro works for me in Word 2010 and 2013 on Windows:

```
Dim eqn As OMath

Sub EquationSearchReplace()
    For Each eqn In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        eqn.ConvertToNormalText
        eqn.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="Det", ReplaceWith:="det", MatchCase:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Replace:=wdFindContinue
        eqn.ConvertToMathText
    Next
End Sub
```

Description of all the parameters for the Find.Execute method can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx).